# Unable to insert record in table using hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Database.
In My Hibernate Mapping file, I have declared Primary key as

```
 <id name="item_Group_Sid" type="int" column="ITEM_GROUP_SID" >
     <generator class="native"/>
 </id>.
```

I am trying to insert a record in the table.
But I am getting error like

> DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

My hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">**</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">**</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">**</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="ItemGroup.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Share your hibernate.cfg.xml file here

Comment: Hi Ransher Singh,Thanks for your reply.
I have updated the Question with hibernate.cfg.xml .
please advise me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `hibernate.dialect` to

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

Comment: Now I am able to insert.Thanks Ransher Singh

Comment: Great..would suggest that you remove url, username and pwd from the cfg.xml file above in your question :)